# 8 people, 4 rounds, two groups of 4 people, can everyone play twice?

Tags: combinations

I have 8 people playing 4 rounds of golf. Playing each round in two groups of four people is it possible that all players play together twice? Trying to work out a draw for it.

Comment: In a $t-(v,k,\lambda)$ block design we always have  $\lambda\binom{v}{t}=b\binom{k}{t}$. In this case the lhs is $2*\binom{8}{2}=56$ while the rhs is $8\binom{4}{2}=48$. So no such design exists.

Answer (score 3):

No. Suppose you have a person $A$ with $7$ friends. Over the course of $4$ rounds of golf, $A$ will have played in a group with exactly $12$ other people. But since he has $7$ friends, he would have to play with $14$ people to play with each twice.

Comment: Is there a way to get it close? At the moment some people play together 3 times and zero with others.